# Advanced Custom Fields comments

Tags: comments, advanced-custom-fields

I have created custom fields for comments with ACF, and I am doing calculation for comments. It works well but for single comment. I would like to calculate all values from specific field for all comments.

For example

```
$number1 = get_field('number1',$comment)
$number2 = get_field('number2',$comment)
$number3 = $number1 + $number2
```

I have this code and it does the calculation for single comment. Now I would like to get values for that fields from all comments for that post, and do the calculation like

```
$number_total = $all_numbers / $number_of_fields
```

Is that possible?

```
$total = $var1+ $var2+ $var3+ $var4+ $var5;
$stat= $total /5;
}
echo $stat; echo '/100';
```

And the var1,var2,var3 are advanced custom fields

```
if( have_rows('safety',$comment) ):
    while ( have_rows('safety',$comment) ) : 
        the_row();
        the_sub_field('field1');
        $field1= get_sub_field('field1');
        $safety_points= $field1;
        $safety_total= $safety_points/5*100;
        echo $safety_total;
    endwhile;
    else :
endif;
```

Comment: Please provide the code for how you are rendering the comments. You will need to loop through each comment, get the field values and add them to an overall array that you can use later to get your totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do calculations with all the comments, you have to fetch them first, and run a loop to do whatever you wish (which you didn't clearly state, so I can't write an accurate answer).

To do so, you can use `get_comments()`:

```
// Get the comments for the current post
$comments = get_comments();
// Run a loop and do stuff
foreach( $comments as $comment ){
    // Do your calculation here. You can access the
    // comment's ID by using $comment->ID;
}
```

Take a look at the codex page that I provided, to see a full list of possible parameters and returned values.

Comment: side note, since codex is deprecated it is better to link to the developer portal, i.e. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works, but it only gets values from first comment and not from all